# Chrome extension js script only running when icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

hi i have been having a problem with creating a chrome extension the extensions js script dosent run unless i click on the icon and let the extension html stay there if i close the little icons menu it stop the javascript file too

is there a way to let the script run when the tab opens and finish the timeout?

and would it be better to use the chrome.alarm then setTimeout?

here is the manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "test",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
 },
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "js": ["main.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

here is the main.js

```
check();



function check(){
setTimeout(function(){ alert('hi'); }, 3000);
}

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
  alert('hi');
})
```

the function and chrome.tabs.onCreated only fires when i click the icon and open the popup html

Comment: this doesn't working either its not running . 
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    alert('hi');
     })

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples): you should declare URL patterns in `"matches"`.

Comment: @wOxxOm i just updated the manifest(locally and in this question) it still doesn't run the Timeout for some reason should i be looking into background script?

Comment: The script still only loads if i  open the popup and it only continue run if i keep the popup open

Comment: 1. Make sure to read the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): the popup is a separate page, 2. chrome.tabs isn't available in content scripts

Comment: Also make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page and reload the tab(s) where your content script runs.